# Countdown timer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make a knowledge competition. I found some code but I can't make Countdown timer start `onload` and when countdown ends redirect to another page.

```js
//circle start
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.e-c-progress');
let indicator = document.getElementById('e-indicator');
let pointer = document.getElementById('e-pointer');
let length = Math.PI * 2 * 100;

progressBar.style.strokeDasharray = length;

function update(value, timePercent) {
  var offset = -length - length * value / (timePercent);
  progressBar.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  pointer.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * value / (timePercent)}deg)`;
};

//circle ends
const displayOutput = document.querySelector('.display-remain-time')
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
const setterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-setter]');

let intervalTimer;
let timeLeft;
let wholeTime = 1 * 60; // manage this to set the whole time 
let isPaused = false;
let isStarted = false;


update(wholeTime, wholeTime); //refreshes progress bar
displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);

function changeWholeTime(seconds) {
  if ((wholeTime + seconds) > 0) {
    wholeTime += seconds;
    update(wholeTime, wholeTime);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < setterBtns.length; i++) {
  setterBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var param = this.dataset.setter;
    switch (param) {
      case 'minutes-plus':
        changeWholeTime(1 * 60);
        break;
      case 'minutes-minus':
        changeWholeTime(-1 * 60);
        break;
      case 'seconds-plus':
        changeWholeTime(1);
        break;
      case 'seconds-minus':
        changeWholeTime(-1);
        break;
    }
    displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
  });
}

function timer(seconds) { //counts time, takes seconds
  let remainTime = Date.now() + (seconds * 1000);
  displayTimeLeft(seconds);

  intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeLeft = Math.round((remainTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalTimer);
      isStarted = false;
      setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.disabled = false;
        btn.style.opacity = 1;
      });
      displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
      pauseBtn.classList.remove('pause');
      pauseBtn.classList.add('play');
      return;
    }
    displayTimeLeft(timeLeft);
  }, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer(event) {
  if (isStarted === false) {
    timer(wholeTime);
    isStarted = true;
    this.classList.remove('play');
    this.classList.add('pause');

    setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.disabled = true;
      btn.style.opacity = 0.9;
    });

  } else if (isPaused) {
    this.classList.remove('play');
    this.classList.add('pause');
    timer(timeLeft);
    isPaused = isPaused ? false : true
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('pause');
    this.classList.add('play');
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    isPaused = isPaused ? false : true;
  }
}

function displayTimeLeft(timeLeft) { //displays time on the input
  let minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
  let seconds = timeLeft % 60;
  let displayString = `${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
  displayOutput.textContent = displayString;
  update(timeLeft, wholeTime);
}

pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
```

```css
button[data-setter] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #F7958E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[data-setter]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 left;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #430000;
}

.setters {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 75px;
}

.minutes-set {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 28px;
}

.seconds-set {
  float: right;
}

.controlls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 105px;
  text-align: center;
}

.display-remain-time {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: #430000;
}

#pause {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.play::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #F7958E;
}

.pause::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 5px solid #F7958E;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#pause:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.e-c-base {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #B6B6B6;
  stroke-width: 4px
}

.e-c-progress {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #004eb7;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
}

.e-c-pointer {
  fill: #ff6000;
  stroke: #024078;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#e-pointer {
  transition: transform 0.7s;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Biz Biliriz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Question 1</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="setters">
      <div class="minutes-set">

      </div>
      <div class="seconds-set">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle"> <svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 220 220">
    <g transform="translate(110,110)">
      <circle r="100" class="e-c-base"/>
      <g transform="rotate(-90)">
        <circle r="100" class="e-c-progress"/>
        <g id="e-pointer">
          <circle cx="100" cy="0" r="8" class="e-c-pointer"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    </svg> </div>
    <div class="controlls">
      <div class="display-remain-time">01:00</div>
      <button class="play" id="pause"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="setters">
      <p>Test Question</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to make a knowledge competition. I found some codes but I can't made Countdown timer start onload and when countdown ends redirect to another page. I need help. Thx

Comment: So which part are you having problems with? Finding source code is good but the key is to understand it so you can make the required changes to fit your purpose. This isn't a free writing service so I suggest you take the time to learn/understand it or hire a developer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        //circle start
        let progressBar = document.querySelector('.e-c-progress');
        let indicator = document.getElementById('e-indicator');
        let pointer = document.getElementById('e-pointer');
        let length = Math.PI * 2 * 100;

        progressBar.style.strokeDasharray = length;

        function update(value, timePercent) {
          var offset = -length - length * value / (timePercent);
          progressBar.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
          pointer.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * value / (timePercent)}deg)`;
        };

        //circle ends
        const displayOutput = document.querySelector('.display-remain-time')
        const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
        const setterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-setter]');

        let intervalTimer;
        let timeLeft;
        let wholeTime = 1 * 60; // manage this to set the whole time 
        let isPaused = false;
        let isStarted = false;


        update(wholeTime, wholeTime); //refreshes progress bar
        displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);

        function changeWholeTime(seconds) {
          if ((wholeTime + seconds) > 0) {
            wholeTime += seconds;
            update(wholeTime, wholeTime);
          }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < setterBtns.length; i++) {
          setterBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            var param = this.dataset.setter;
            switch (param) {
              case 'minutes-plus':
                changeWholeTime(1 * 60);
                break;
              case 'minutes-minus':
                changeWholeTime(-1 * 60);
                break;
              case 'seconds-plus':
                changeWholeTime(1);
                break;
              case 'seconds-minus':
                changeWholeTime(-1);
                break;
            }
            displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
          });
        }

        function timer(seconds) { //counts time, takes seconds
          let remainTime = Date.now() + (seconds * 1000);
          displayTimeLeft(seconds);

          intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
            timeLeft = Math.round((remainTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
            if (timeLeft < 0) {
              location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; // redirect
              clearInterval(intervalTimer);
              isStarted = false;
              setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
                btn.disabled = false;
                btn.style.opacity = 1;
              });
              displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
              pauseBtn.classList.remove('pause');
              pauseBtn.classList.add('play');
              return;
            }
            displayTimeLeft(timeLeft);
          }, 1000);
        }

        function pauseTimer(event) {
          if (isStarted === false) {
            timer(wholeTime);
            isStarted = true;
            this.classList.remove('play');
            this.classList.add('pause');

            setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
              btn.disabled = true;
              btn.style.opacity = 0.9;
            });

          } else if (isPaused) {
            this.classList.remove('play');
            this.classList.add('pause');
            timer(timeLeft);
            isPaused = isPaused ? false : true
          } else {
            this.classList.remove('pause');
            this.classList.add('play');
            clearInterval(intervalTimer);
            isPaused = isPaused ? false : true;
          }
        }

        function displayTimeLeft(timeLeft) { //displays time on the input
          let minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
          let seconds = timeLeft % 60;
          let displayString = `${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
          displayOutput.textContent = displayString;
          update(timeLeft, wholeTime);
        }

        pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
        pauseTimer(); // run at page ready
```

```css
        button[data-setter] {
          outline: none;
          background: transparent;
          border: none;
          font-family: 'Arial';
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 18px;
          width: 25px;
          height: 30px;
          color: #F7958E;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        button[data-setter]:hover {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .container {
          float: left;
          position: relative;
          top: 0px;
          left: 25px;
          width: 300px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .sidebar {
          float: right;
          position: relative;
          top: 0px;
          width: 50%;
          margin: 0 left;
          font-family: 'Arial';
          font-weight: 100;
          font-size: 35px;
          color: #430000;
        }

        .setters {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          top: 75px;
        }

        .minutes-set {
          float: left;
          margin-right: 28px;
        }

        .seconds-set {
          float: right;
        }

        .controlls {
          position: absolute;
          left: 75px;
          top: 105px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .display-remain-time {
          font-family: 'Roboto';
          font-weight: 100;
          font-size: 65px;
          color: #430000;
        }

        #pause {
          outline: none;
          background: transparent;
          border: none;
          margin-top: 10px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          position: relative;
        }

        .play::before {
          display: block;
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 8px;
          left: 16px;
          border-top: 15px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
          border-left: 22px solid #F7958E;
        }

        .pause::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 8px;
          left: 12px;
          width: 15px;
          height: 30px;
          background-color: transparent;
          border-radius: 1px;
          border: 5px solid #F7958E;
          border-top: none;
          border-bottom: none;
        }

        #pause:hover {
          opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .e-c-base {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #B6B6B6;
          stroke-width: 4px
        }

        .e-c-progress {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #004eb7;
          stroke-width: 4px;
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
        }

        .e-c-pointer {
          fill: #ff6000;
          stroke: #024078;
          stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        #e-pointer {
          transition: transform 0.7s;
        }

        h1 {
          margin-top: 50px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        body {
          background-color: #f7f7f7;
        }
```

```html
        <html>

        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>Biz Biliriz</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <h1>Question 1</h1>

          <div class="container">
            <div class="setters">
              <div class="minutes-set">

              </div>
              <div class="seconds-set">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle"> <svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 220 220">
            <g transform="translate(110,110)">
              <circle r="100" class="e-c-base"/>
              <g transform="rotate(-90)">
                <circle r="100" class="e-c-progress"/>
                <g id="e-pointer">
                  <circle cx="100" cy="0" r="8" class="e-c-pointer"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
            </svg> </div>
            <div class="controlls">
              <div class="display-remain-time">01:00</div>
              <button class="play" id="pause"></button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="setters">
              <p>Test Question</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I think that's what you need, just added two lines in the JS codes;

Comment: The solution you have provided has a **syntax error** *"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined",*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, This is running on page load & redirecting

```js
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.e-c-progress');
let indicator = document.getElementById('e-indicator');
let pointer = document.getElementById('e-pointer');
let length = Math.PI * 2 * 100;

progressBar.style.strokeDasharray = length;

function update(value, timePercent) {
  var offset = -length - length * value / (timePercent);
  progressBar.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  pointer.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * value / (timePercent)}deg)`;
};

//circle ends
const displayOutput = document.querySelector('.display-remain-time')
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
const setterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-setter]');

let intervalTimer;
let timeLeft;
let wholeTime = 1 * 60; // manage this to set the whole time 
let isPaused = false;
let isStarted = false;


update(wholeTime, wholeTime); //refreshes progress bar
displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);

function changeWholeTime(seconds) {
  if ((wholeTime + seconds) > 0) {
    wholeTime += seconds;
    update(wholeTime, wholeTime);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < setterBtns.length; i++) {
  setterBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var param = this.dataset.setter;
    switch (param) {
      case 'minutes-plus':
        changeWholeTime(1 * 60);
        break;
      case 'minutes-minus':
        changeWholeTime(-1 * 60);
        break;
      case 'seconds-plus':
        changeWholeTime(1);
        break;
      case 'seconds-minus':
        changeWholeTime(-1);
        break;
    }
    displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
  });
}

function timer(seconds) { //counts time, takes seconds
  let remainTime = Date.now() + (seconds * 1000);
  displayTimeLeft(seconds);

  intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeLeft = Math.round((remainTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
    //here you redirect after timelfet 0 or circle complete
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; // redirect
      clearInterval(intervalTimer);
      isStarted = false;
      setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.disabled = false;
        btn.style.opacity = 1;
  
      });
      displayTimeLeft(wholeTime);
      pauseBtn.classList.remove('pause');
      pauseBtn.classList.add('play');
      return;
    }
    displayTimeLeft(timeLeft);
  }, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer(event) {
  if (isStarted === false) {
    timer(wholeTime);
    isStarted = true;
    this.classList.remove('play');
    this.classList.add('pause');

    setterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.disabled = true;
      btn.style.opacity = 0.9;
    });

  } else if (isPaused) {
    this.classList.remove('play');
    this.classList.add('pause');
    timer(timeLeft);
    isPaused = isPaused ? false : true
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('pause');
    this.classList.add('play');
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    isPaused = isPaused ? false : true;
  }
}

function displayTimeLeft(timeLeft) { //displays time on the input
  let minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
  let seconds = timeLeft % 60;
  let displayString = `${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
  displayOutput.textContent = displayString;
  update(timeLeft, wholeTime);
}
//here you call your function onload
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  pauseTimer(event);   
});
```

```css
<style>
button[data-setter] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #F7958E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[data-setter]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 left;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #430000;
}

.setters {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 75px;
}

.minutes-set {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 28px;
}

.seconds-set {
  float: right;
}

.controlls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 105px;
  text-align: center;
}

.display-remain-time {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: #430000;
}

#pause {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.play::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #F7958E;
}

.pause::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 5px solid #F7958E;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#pause:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.e-c-base {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #B6B6B6;
  stroke-width: 4px
}

.e-c-progress {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #004eb7;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
}

.e-c-pointer {
  fill: #ff6000;
  stroke: #024078;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#e-pointer {
  transition: transform 0.7s;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Biz Biliriz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Question 1</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="setters">
      <div class="minutes-set">

      </div>
      <div class="seconds-set">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle"> <svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 220 220">
    <g transform="translate(110,110)">
      <circle r="100" class="e-c-base"/>
      <g transform="rotate(-90)">
        <circle r="100" class="e-c-progress"/>
        <g id="e-pointer">
          <circle cx="100" cy="0" r="8" class="e-c-pointer"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    </svg> </div>
    <div class="controlls">
      <div class="display-remain-time">01:00</div>
      <button class="play" id="pause"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="setters">
      <p>Test Question</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a `foo` `function` and want it to run on load. You can do it using the `onload` property of the `body`:

```
<body onload="foo();">
    <!-- something -->
</body>
```

Or you can do it in Javascript like this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Now, how should `foo` look like:

```
function foo() {
    var initialTime = 60000; //A minute
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!(--initialTime)) {
            //redirect
        }
        //Do something
    }, 1000);
}
```